# Target specific h2 on a page

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML like this.

```
<div class="platform-content">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="entry">
      <article class="post-type-page id123 page type-page status-private hentry" id="id123">
        <section class="entry-header">
          <h2 class="entry-title">Heading Text</h2>
        </section>
```

I need to target just that one h2 element in order to change its color with css. I've tried doing the following.

```
#id123 h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

It works, except every h2 on the page changes to red. I also can't just target h2 directly either as then it affects other pages as well. I can't seam to figure out how to target just that one specific h2 on that page only and not every one of them on the page.

Further down the page I have some form fields that have h2 elements in them like this. I don't want these to change to red.

```
<li id='field_18_75' class='gfield gsection field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible'>
  <h2 class='gsection_title'>Title Text</h2>
</li>
```

The trouble is, all of this html is generated and I don't have any control over that. So I can't add a custom id to the element for example.

Comment: You only have one h2 in the code in the question. Hard to say, without seeing the other h2s that you say are being targeted too

Comment: You could try using `h2:first-of-type` if it's the first h2 on the page, but like CertainPerformance said, it's hard to know if it'll work without seeing the other h2s

Comment: If `entry-title` is unique then you can use `#id123 h2.entry-title` instead.

Comment: Thank you David Angulo, that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Angulo - If entry-title is unique then you can use #id123 h2.entry-title instead.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as what my answer says? I don't think there was a need to post a separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to capture only the elements with **nth-child(n)**

```css
#id123 section h2:nth-child(1) {
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="entry">
      <article class="post-type-page id123 page type-page status-private hentry" id="id123">
        <section class="entry-header">
          
<h2 class="entry-title">Heading Text</h2><h2 class="entry-title">Heading Text</h2>
        </section>
        </article>
        </section>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you specified an `id` on the `<h2>` element, the code you specified should work. Keep in mind that ids on each page should be unique so the CSS instruction `#id123 h2 { color: red; }` should affect only the `<h2 id="id123"></h2>` element.

---

**Example:**

```css
h2 {
  color: blue;
}

#id123 h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="platform-content">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="entry">
      <article class="post-type-page id123 page type-page status-private hentry" id="id123">
        <section class="entry-header">
          <h2 class="entry-title">Heading Text</h2>
        </section>
       </article
    </section>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="platform-content">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="entry">
      <article class="post-type-page id123 page type-page status-private hentry" id="id124">
        <section class="entry-header">
          <h2 class="entry-title">Heading Text</h2>
        </section>
       </article
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a particular  tag to be of red color, then give it a unique id and then set it's color as red.

```
#uniqueId {
   color : red
}


<h2 id = "uniqueId">Heading Text</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give id to that particular `h2` element:

```
<h2 class="entry-title" id="my-id">Heading Text</h2>
```

then in css:

```
#my-id {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: @DavidAngulo then it won't work, let me edit the answer.

Comment: In this case you can do it by using specific descendant selector css

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2 id="idA" class="entry-title">Heading Text</h2>
```

Put specific id on h2 tag.

```
#idA{
   color : red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use :nth-child for achieve this.. Like this check my answer..

```css
.entry-header h2:nth-child(1){
  color:red;

}

.entry-header h2:nth-child(2){
  color:blue

}
.entry-header h2:nth-child(3){
  color:yellow

}
```

```html
<div class="platform-content">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="entry">
      <article class="post-type-page id123 page type-page status-private hentry" id="id123">
        <section class="entry-header">
          <h2 class="entry-title">Heading Text1</h2>
          <h2 class="entry-title">Heading Text2</h2>
          <h2 class="entry-title">Heading Text3</h2>
          <h2 class="entry-title">Heading Text4</h2>
   </section>
```